# Nightly data export/import from SQL Server to MySQL using DTSX Package

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have been tasked with copying data from a clients SQL Server into their websites MySQL server on a nightly basis.

> Create a nightly data import from the client’s SQL Server into the
>   website DB using something that equates to the DTSX packages that I’ve
>   attached to this message.

I am unfamiliar with SSIS etc and am having trouble getting my around how I would do this on the web server side.

I would personally prefer connecting directly to the SQL Server rather than duplicating data which is how I have done it many times before.

Comment: This is balanced somewhere between "too broad" and "unclear what you're asking". You haven't posed a coding question here. FWIW, SSIS is up to the task at hand if you're willing to invest the time to learn to use it.

Comment: From what I can work out, SSIS is ran on Server A (SQL Server) and has the capability of exporting from the database based on the DTSX files and could send the files via FTP to our Web Server which could be imported into MySQL - if this is the case, then that makes more sense!